# Can I "pause" tracking to avoid tracking app getting suspended in case of start by system event?

Tags: ios, gps, tracking, suspend

my problem is, that a tracking app gets suspended after some minutes, if tracking is started by the system event of crossing a geo-fence. The idea is, to have the app tracking, when user is inside a geo-fence, and have no tracking activity, when user is outside. But this does not work due to ios app suspension.

I don´t know, if what I read in other threads relates to this problem: ...pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically. set this property to NO and it works in background pretty well relates to the problem...

Is there something like "pausing" tracking, so crossing a geo-fence is not seen as a system event "starting" tracking?

Comment: You should show some code, but if you have correctly enabled background location mode then your app should continue to receive location updates.

Comment: Hi Paul, once again thanks a lot for your quick answer. You look very experienced to me and I have a bad conscience asking so many question without returning anything helpful. Is it possible to book you for a day or some hours to solve some problems together with my developer? (I hope I did not violate any forum rules I could not find by asking this.)

Comment: Thanks. Just sent you a message, but somehow my messages sometime land in the spam.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Did not try via google hangouts.